# Process control - How to wait for child process to complete?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using C `fork()`, parent process can `waitpid(childPid, &returnStatus, 0);` for child process to exit.

In python,

```
completed = subprocess.run(['ls', '-1'])
```

[CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) instance does not give control to parent process to wait for child process. Child process can run for time more then normal.

How to wait for child process to complete? How to abort/kill child process on failure, without a pid?

Comment: Does `subprocess.run()` & `subprocess.call()` internally use C `fork()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-1'])
p.wait()
```

To see if the subprocess is already finished, look at `p.poll()`.  If this is `None`, the process is still running.  If it is a number, that's the process's exit code.

Comment: Is `subprocess.Popen()` without `PIPE` arguments, like a normal `fork()`?

Comment: Exactly.  You can give more information about how to redirect the file descriptors, but if you say nothing, it's like `fork()` and `exec()` wrapped in a nice Python object.

Comment: In C, process control `fork()` is handled separately from IPC `popen()`, unlike in python, fork and pipes are in single call `subprocess.Popen()`. pipe is one of many IPC mechanism where as fork is process control. Bit confusing

Comment: @overexchange - _Addendum_: If you need to, as stated in your question, `abort/kill child process` you'll have to use the `timeout` argument which is not available prior to Python 3.3. You can do it manually, tho, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44522570/7553525).

Comment: The CPython implementation will probably do that (or use `clone(2)` which essentially boils down to the same thing).  In general, creating a new process in a Unix environment needs to use either of the two system calls.  There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Only parent processor can use wait(), child processor can’t. But child processor can use pause() instead to wait a signal to come.